# Entropy of Isothermal Expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, heat-engine

I know that the change in entropy is 0 for reversible processes and is nonzero for irreversible ones. For isothermal free expansion (not reversible) the change in entropy is nonzero (i.e. proportional to the log of the volume ratio). However, consider an quasistatic isothermal expansion (an isotherm curve in a PV diagram, or an isotherm in a carnot cycle). Using the thermodynamic identity $dE = TdS - PdV$ I obtain $dS = \frac{dE}{T} + \frac{P}{T}dV = \frac{C_v dT}{T} + \frac{nR}{V}dV$, or, after integrating, $\Delta S = nR ln(V_2/V_1) > 0$. This suggest that the quasistatic process is irreversible, right? However, I think I have learned that this quasistatic isothermal processes is reversible. Can anyone explain why this "reversible" process has nonzero entropy change? Is the thing that I learned (this process should be reversible) incorrect? Or did I do something wrong in the calculations?

Comment: Your initial statement is incorrect.  The change in entropy is zero of a reversible process is zero for the combination of system plus surroundings.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks